# How can I add text inside a DIV but not have it visible or using any space on my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div>{{ modal.data.text }}</div>
```

How can I hide the data that shows from view. I don't want it to have any height / width but some other reasons I want it to be added to the DOM.

Note the {{ are from AngularJS and it will substitute the {{ }} for some text when the page displays.

Comment: `<div style="display:none;">{{ modal.data.text }}</div>`???

Comment: <div style="display:none;"></div> ..u tried dis?

Answer (score 2):

A more Angular-y way:

```
<div ng-hide="modal.data.text" ng-bind="modal.data.text"></div>
```

**Explanation:**
The div will hide when `modal.data.text` evaluates to true (contains some text in your case), and will also bind the value of `modal.data.text` to the inner HTML of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<div style="display: none">{{ modal.data.text }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#mydiv {
   display:none;
}

<div id="mydiv">{{ modal.data.text }}</div>
```